# using realm-web with React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, realm, mongodb-atlas

First of all, I am new with react. It has been two weeks since I am working with it

I am trying to use "realm-web" with react (web). I would like to write realm provider in order to access realmApp everywhere in my application. However my attempts didn't go well. The application is giving " Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". But beside this error, I am sure there is more to be handled.

Here is my implementation:

```
const RealmProvider: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLElement, PropTypes> = ({ app: realmApp, store, children }) => {

  let realm = useTypedSelector(store => store.realm);

  let app = useRef<Realm.App>();

  const credentials = React.useMemo(() => Realm.Credentials.apiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_REALM_APP_API_KEY!), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.current = realmApp
    console.log(realmApp)

    if (app.current.currentUser == null) {
      loadingRealmApp()
      app.current.logIn(credentials)
        .then((res) => store.dispatch(storeRealmApp(res)))
      //.catch(reason => console.log("RealmError", reason));
    }

    //Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      app.current?.currentUser?.logOut().then(() =>
        store.dispatch(unloadRealmApp())
      );
    };
  }, [realmApp, store]);

  return (
    <>
      { React.Children.only(children)}
    </>
  );
}

export default RealmProvider;
```

---

Reducer

```
// Actions
const STORE_REALM_APP = 'atlas/realm/STORE_REALM_APP'
const STORE_REALM_APP_ERROR = 'atlas/realm/STORE_USER_ERROR'
const UNLOAD_REALM_APP = 'atlas/realm/UNLOAD_REALM_APP'
const LOADING_REALM_APP = 'atlas/realm/LOADING_REALM_APP'




type State = {
    //realmApp?: Realm.App
    user?: Realm.User
    isLoadingRealmApp: boolean
}

const initialState: State = {
    //realmApp: undefined,
    user: undefined,
    isLoadingRealmApp: false
};

type RealmAction = {
    payload: Realm.User
} & Action;

// Reducer
const realmReducer = function (state: State = initialState, action: RealmAction): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case STORE_REALM_APP:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoadingRealmApp: false,
                user: action.payload
            }
        case LOADING_REALM_APP:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoadingRealmApp: true
            }
        case STORE_REALM_APP_ERROR:
        case UNLOAD_REALM_APP:
            return {
                ...state,
                user: undefined,
                isLoadingRealmApp: false
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default realmReducer;




export function storeRealmApp(app: Realm.User) {
    console.log("storeRealmApp", app)
    return {
        type: STORE_REALM_APP,
        payload: app
    }
}

export function loadingRealmApp() {
    return {
        type: LOADING_REALM_APP
    }
}

export function storeRealmAppError(reason: any) {
    return {
        type: STORE_REALM_APP_ERROR,
        payload: reason
    }
}

export function unloadRealmApp() {
    return {
        type: UNLOAD_REALM_APP
    }
}
```

Realm.ts

```
const realmApp: Realm.App = new Realm.App({ id: process.env.REACT_APP_REALM_APP_ID!, app: { name: "Atlas" } });

//const mongodb = realmApp.currentUser!.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")

const useMongodb = () => {

    const user = useTypedSelector(store => store.realm.user);
    console.log(user)
    return user!.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas");
}


export { realmApp, useMongodb }
```

I guess I am doing something wrong, or this is not the way of doing this. I need some help :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs it, I figure it out.

```
import React from "react";
import * as Realm from "realm-web";

type ContextType = {
    currentUser: Realm.User,
    logIn: (credentials: Realm.Credentials) => void
    logOut: () => void
} & Realm.App

const RealmAppContext = React.createContext<ContextType>({
} as any);

export const useRealmApp = () => {
    const app = React.useContext(RealmAppContext);
    if (!app) {
        throw new Error(
            `You must call useRealmApp() inside of a <RealmAppProvider />`
        );
    }
    return app;
};

export const useMongodb = () => {
    const app = React.useContext<ContextType>(RealmAppContext);
    const mongodb = app.currentUser.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
    if (!mongodb) {
        throw new Error(
            `You must call useRealmApp() inside of a <RealmAppProvider />`
        );
    }
    return mongodb;
};


type PropTypes = {
    appId: string,
    //children: JSX.Element
}

export const RealmAppProvider: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLElement, PropTypes> = ({ appId, children }) => {
    const [app, setApp] = React.useState(new Realm.App(appId));
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setApp(new Realm.App(appId));
    }, [appId]);

    // Wrap the Realm.App object's user state with React state
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = React.useState(app.currentUser);
    async function logIn(credentials: Realm.Credentials) {
        await app.logIn(credentials);
        // If successful, app.currentUser is the user that just logged in
        setCurrentUser(app.currentUser);
    }
    async function logOut() {
        // Log out the currently active user
        await app.currentUser?.logOut();
        // If another user was logged in too, they're now the current user.
        // Otherwise, app.currentUser is null.
        setCurrentUser(app.currentUser);
    }

    const wrapped = { ...app, currentUser, logIn, logOut };

    return (
        <RealmAppContext.Provider value={wrapped as any}>
            {children}
        </RealmAppContext.Provider>
    );
};
```